# Flink 1.4 Column 'rowtime' not found in any table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am following the documentation to [configure a TableSource with a rowtime attribute](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#configure-a-rowtime-attribute).

I register the `timestamp` field as follows

```
KafkaTableSource source = Kafka08JsonTableSource.builder()// set Kafka topic
            .forTopic("alerting")
            // set Kafka consumer properties
            .withKafkaProperties(getKafkaProperties())
            // set Table schema
            .withSchema(TableSchema.builder()
                    .field("tenant", Types.STRING())
                    .field("message", Types.STRING())
                    .field("frequency", Types.LONG())
                    .field("timestamp", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP()).build())
            .failOnMissingField(true)
            .withRowtimeAttribute(
                    // "timestamp" is rowtime attribute
                    "timestamp",
                    // value of "timestamp" is extracted from existing field with same name
                    new ExistingField("timestamp"),
                    // values of "timestamp" are at most out-of-order by 30 seconds
                    new BoundedOutOfOrderTimestamps(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)))
            .build();

    //register the alerting topic as kafka
    tEnv.registerTableSource("kafka", source);

    Table results = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT tenant, message, SUM(frequency) " +
            "FROM kafka " +
            "GROUP BY HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL '1' SECOND, INTERVAL '5' SECOND), tenant, message");

    tEnv.toAppendStream(results, Row.class).print();
```

and get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: SQL validation failed. From line 1, column 64 to line 1, column 70: Column 'rowtime' not found in any table
>       at org.apache.flink.table.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.validate(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:93)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.sqlQuery(TableEnvironment.scala:561)
>       at oracle.flink.demo.KafkaSQLStream.main(KafkaSQLStream.java:62)
>   Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 64 to line 1, column 70: Column 'rowtime' not found in any table
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in your table `kafka` is called `timestamp` and not `rowtime`. So you should use call the attribute by its name `timestamp` instead of `rowtime`.

Note that `TIMESTAMP` is a keyword in SQL, so you should either rename the `timestamp` attribute or escape the attribute name with backticks (`):

```
tEnv.sqlQuery(
  "SELECT tenant, message, SUM(frequency) " +
  "FROM kafka " +
  "GROUP BY HOP(`timestamp`, INTERVAL '1' SECOND, INTERVAL '5' SECOND), tenant, message");
```

Btw. `BoundedOutOfOrderTimestamps` of one day is actually quite a lot. This can cause significant processing latency and state sizes, as the query will collect data for one day before it starts emitting results and discarding state.

Comment: I'm now getting a "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Could not retrieve BlobServer address." after changing the timestamp to updated?

Comment: "SELECT tenant, message, SUM(frequency) " +
                "FROM kafka " +
                "GROUP BY HOP(updated, INTERVAL '1' SECOND, INTERVAL '5' SECOND), tenant, message"

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Could not retrieve BlobServer address.
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor$1.call(JobSubmissionClientActor.java:166)
 at akka.dispatch.Futures$$anonfun$future$1.apply(Future.scala:97)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

Comment: If there is am example/github of Kafka##JsonTableSource + SQL + windowing that I can just follow, that would be fantastic!

Comment: That's a different issue and not related to the SQL or Table API. Probably also not to your source code but to your Flink setup. I'd suggest to start a new question or reach out to the mailing list.